# Unix TCSH: Looping through GREP results using FOREACH not working

Tags: unix, foreach, grep, tcsh

I am trying to do a simple task. Grep a list of names in a text file, feed it into foreach loop, and do something with it, example maybe delete or copy the file name.

But I can't seem to get the results of grep to feed into foreach's variable.

```
foreach key ( `grep -r '*' /nfs/png/disks/png_vlvpe_disk007/tvpv/prod_suite/users/clwong/Pat_Label_Remove_C0_17_17_vrevL2List/vrevL2_append.txt` ) 
rm $key
end
```

Any idea?

Comment: The grep command prints out correctly if I just use it to search for the lines. But when I quote it in back ticks to feed into for each it fails. Why ? Find works well .

Comment: What does the file content look like?  It might be a problem with the input field separator

Comment: file1haha*
file2haha*
file3haha*

each is separated by newline

Comment: Ah, filename globbing issue.  I think if you look at my answer now, it will help you :)

Comment: From the name, I think the issue is because the result from grep was globbed.... As such it can't feed into foreach. Correct?

Comment: If $key has an asterisk, I believe you'll need to double-quote it: `rm "$key"`.

Comment: It feeds into the foreach fine, but the contents of the foreach - after the backticked string is replaced by the output of its execution  - is itself interpreted by the shell.  @JosephQuinsey, even quoted strings are globbed (tried it).  Single quoting would work - if it wasn't a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here was to *disable* file globbing with `set noglob`

For a list of files such as:

```
dfarrell% cat files.txt
file1.txt*
file2.txt*
file3.txt*
file4.txt*
```

You could operate on each file with

```
dfarrell% set noglob; foreach file ( `cat files.txt` )  
foreach? unset noglob
foreach? rm -v "$file"
foreach? set noglob
foreach? end
file1.txt*
file2.txt*
file3.txt*
file4.txt*
```

You can re-enable globbing when done with `unset noglob`

Note here I'm typing into the command line which is why you se the `foreach?` prompt.  In a shell script in a file you wouldn't type that, or see it that way - it comes from the shell.

Comment: I thought cat concatenates the contents into a single string ?

Comment: cat reads the contents of one or more files.  It's kind of like a grep that matches everything - but if you're not applying regular expressions you may as well just list the file.

Comment: Hmm, need some help... After setting noglob, the grep works just fine, but then inside the loop I need to use cp $file /destination, and $file = filename* , which is has a wildcard, and it completely failed with noglob set....

Comment: You can turn noglob off at the beginning of the loop, and then turn it back on at the end!

Comment: well I did tried that, no use. Because when i turned glob back on in the loop, the foreach loop fails. Dan, thanks for answering. I know something new today.

Comment: I added set/unset noglob to my example - I'm pretty sure that would work if you turned it off at the beginning and on at the end like that.